# How to perform validations on the select items using Javascript or Struts1.3.8?

Tags: java, validation, jsp, struts-validation

I'm using Struts 1.3.8. In my JSP there is a select option with dynamically populated items in it.
How do I perform validations on the select option when the user doesn't select any item?
The *required* rule is not working. Any idea or suggestions? Reply is highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

create temporary option like

```
<select name="selectItem">
   <option value="-1" >-----Select-----</option>
   .
   .
</select>
```

call java script function on form submit where check something like

```
if((document.Form1.selectItem[document.Form1.selectItem.selectedIndex].value)=='-1')
 return false;
else
 return true;
```